# How do I make a square in C++

Tags: c++

How to make a square box in C++?

[image: a square box]

Comment: Welcome, some additional information would be helpful. Which "script" are you referring to, what have you tried, and what libraries are you using?

Comment: Are you trying to draw a box in text?

Comment: I was nine when I started programming too! Good job. However, I remember having figured out basic algorithms (such as this one) myself. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Also, what operating system are you running on?  You may be better off with something like C#, ie. MS Visual Studio.

Comment: What computer (platform) or operating system: Window, Linux, ???

Comment: Please edit your question with the code you have.

Comment: Note to self: Start questions with _"I'm nine years old"_.  But seriously, keep at it :) I was 20 when I started, and I regret that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#age Although you are now old enough so yay!

Answer (score 16):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do exactly but it sounds like one of my first programs (which printed "BEAUTY EH?" to the screen in huge graphics. Drawing the question mark was really hard.).  But here is a program that displays a box like this:

```
********************************************************************************
*                                                                              *
*                                                                              *
*                                                                              *
*                                                                              *
*                                                                              *
*                                                                              *
*                                                                              *
*                                                                              *
********************************************************************************
```

And here's the program:

```
#include <cstdlib>  // It's always best to include this file before any others.
#include <iostream> // This is so we can use "cout"

int main()
{
    // first let's save ourselves a little typing
    using namespace std;

    // We're going to draw a box of stars ("*").
    // It will be 80 characters wide by 10 rows tall.
    //
    // Since we're writing to the console using 'cout',
    // we're just going to write one line at a time,
    // and then issue a carraige return to start printing
    // on the next line.

    // First let's draw the top "wall", which is a solid 
    // row of 80 stars, one at a time
    for (int column = 0; column < 80; ++column)
    {
        cout << "*";
    }
    // now print a carraige return, so we can start printing on the next line
    cout << "\n";

    // Now we're going to print the sides.
    // There are 8 rows here.  Each row is a star, followed by
    // 78 spaces, followed by another star and a carraige return.
    for (int row = 0; row < 8; ++row)
    {
        // print the left "wall"
        cout << "*";
        // now print 78 spaces
        for (int column = 0; column < 78; ++column)
        {
            cout << " ";
        }
        // finally print the right "wall" and a carraige return
        cout << "*\n";
        // continue the for loop to print the next row
    }

    // Once the loop is done, we can print the bottom wall the same way we printed the top one.
    for (int column = 0; column < 80; ++column)
    {
        cout << "*";
    }
    // now print a carraige return, so we can start printing on the next line
    cout << "\n";

}
```

Comment: Nice answer, I had thougth to write something like that, but yours answers was too good. Just a minimum correction, to print 78 spaces, you need to sweep your loop from 0 to column < 78, not 79.

Answer (score 1):

Using ascii characters can help you make a great looking box.  If you look at the table on this site:  http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/box-drawing-character-ascii-code-179.html , you can see that 185-188, and 200-207 line up pretty nicely to make a box.  I use 187 and 188 to draw the right corners, 200 and 201 for the left corners, and 186 and 205 for vertical and horizontal walls.  Remember that integers and characters are the same thing in the compiler's mind, so if you assign these integer values to a char variable, it will output the ascii value.